# standard matrix of a orthogonal projection linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am try to solve part (b) of question 1 in:
[image]

I'm not exactly sure how I should approach part (b). My attempt at the question so far is to plug in the elementary basis vectors $e_1, e_2, e_3$ into the span of vector given to see what the linear transformation does to $e_1, e_2, e_3$ and form the standard matrix from there which hasn't worked so far. Any hints?

Comment: Try to think about how you would (orthogonally) project a vector $x$ onto the span of $e_1$ and $e_2$. Once you've done this, see if you can write it as a matrix operation.

Comment: do you mean project $e1$ and $e2$ with the span vectors?
i.e.  ((1,1,0)($e1$))($e1$) and so forth with $e2$ ?

Comment: Basically. I assume by $((1,1,0)(e1))$ you mean the inner product?

Comment: yes, inner product. So by computing what I suggested, I should be able to figure out the standard matrix for the linear transformation?

Comment: Sorry, instead of $e_1$ and $e_2$ i should have said $v_1$ and $v_2$, your orthonormal basis vectors for the span of $V$.

Comment: so $v1$ and $v2$ are obtained by gram-schmidt on the span vectors of $V$ ?

Comment: You say that your attempt hasn’t worked. What problems are you having? Your basic approach is sound, so if you show your work, someone might be able to find a simple error that you’re making.

Comment: The simplest method, not even hinted at yet in comments or answers, is to compute the projection onto the orthogonal complement of $V$—that’s just projection onto a single vector—and subtract that from the original vectors.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comments since they were getting long.

Suppose we have a set of orthonormal vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$. If we want to compute the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto the span of $v_1$ and $v_2$ we would first project $x$ onto $v_1$:
$$
y = P_1x = (v_1^Tx) v_1
$$
and then onto $v_2$:
$$
P_2x = (v_2^Tx)v_2
$$

Therefore,
$$
Px = (v_1^Tx)v_1 + (v_2^Tx)v_2
$$
We can write this as the sum of rank-1 outer products:
$$
Px = v_1v_1^Tx + v_2v_2^Tx = (v_1v_1^T+v_2v_2^T)x
$$

Therefore,
$$
P = VV^T = [v_1 v_2]
\begin{bmatrix}
v_1^T \\ v_2^T
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are not orthonormal you can first orthonormalize them (using Gram-Schmidt) and then do this. Alternatively, you can use the formula Foobaz John gave.

Comment: if I'm interpreting this correctly, $P$ gives the standard matrix of this linear transformation yes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. We note that for $y\in \mathbb{R}^3$ the projected vector $Ay$ is such that $y-Ay$ is orthogonal to $V$. In particular if we form a matrix $B$ whose columns are $(1,1,0)^T$ and $(0,0,1)^T$ respectively, we get that
$$
B'(y-Ay)=0.
$$
But $Ay=Bc$ for some $c$ whence
$$
B'(y-Bc)=0\iff B'y=B'Bc
$$
Since $B$ is full-rank, it follows that $B'B$ is invertible whence
$$
c=(B'B)^{-1}B'y\implies Ay=Bc=B(B'B)^{-1}B'y.
$$
So $A=B(B'B)^{-1}B'$.

Comment: this is quite a complex explanation for myself, what exactly is $B'$ in this instance?

Comment: The transpose of the matrix.